# jquery get last div that entered in view

Tags: jquery

I want to get last div that entered in my screen

there are some certain divs that has an attribute of id

I want to get last div that is shown in screen by scrolling down how can I get that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with plain JavaScript:

```
var divs = document.getElementByTagName('div');
var lastDiv = divs[divs.length-1];
```